# SQLite query with where clause

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite database in my application and I want to fetch the rows from the table where I have some particular value in corresponding and when I fetch all rows my app works fine but when I use where clause then I get no data in the cursor object ?
below is my method of SQLite helper class to get data

```
public Cursor getAllNames(String belongsId){
        SQLiteDatabase myDb = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return myDb.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_names + " WHERE BELONGS =" + belongsId ,null);
    }
```

and this is my function call:-

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllNames(belongsId);
```

myDb is the object of my SQLite helper class.

my tble is below:-

```
 sr        names         BELONGS
 1          joe          abc
 2          sid          def
 3          david        abc
```

so basicall I wanna fetch only rows 1 and 3 and all other rows where BELONGS = abc

any little help will be appriciated thanks!

error is below :-

Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abc (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM names WHERE BELONGS = abc

[please click to see full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBEgZ.png)

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abc (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM names WHERE BELONGS = abc

Comment: thanks a lot sir @CL I got my answer HAPPY :)

Comment: @CL sorry to disturb again but can you tell me how I can delete multiple rows with same id like belongsId as in above table If wanna delete the rows having BELONGS = abc  I think this " db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "BELONGS = ?", belongsId); " will delete only one row ?

Comment: This is not a forum; to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button. Anyway, why don't you just try it?